# Can i simulate a key press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

The same way its possible to manually:

```
$('#load_more_content').click();
```

to simulate the item has been clicked (so any attached event will be fired)

can we do the same with the keyboard keys?

*something like*:

```
e.key = '27';
```

`$(window).keyDown(e);` ?

so its simulated the ESCAPE key to be pressed? (so any attached event will be fired)

Thanks a lot