# Simulate / Fake a keypress in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, simulate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

--EDIT--

Long story short I have a swiffy object on the page and I can "control" it using different keypresses and one of them is by pressing "P".. right now, if I physically press P it performs a given animation... The code below is not working because that animation isn't happening after the 2 seconds... (I've added alert's to test and it fires, but the actual keypress simulation doesn't work...

If your curious, this is purely for animation purposes... I'm building a rapid-prototype... maybe I should be asking how to control a swiffy object (the same way the letter P does it) instead of asking how to fake the letter P press? o.o

Anyway, is this even possible?

--EDIT--

heads-up: I'm pretty new to jQuery and JavaScript so I apologize for the question. I've searched the site for my question and found a closed thread, but since I can't make it work I'm opening this new one.

So basically I want to simulate/fake a keypress of the letter P. From that closed thread it looked like it's possible and here's what I got:

```
setTimeout(function() { triggerP() }, 2000);
function triggerP()
{
     var evP = jQuery.Event("keypress");
     evP.which = 112;
     $(this).trigger(evP);
}
```

I also have this (just wanted to make sure I have a proper version that allows for this):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there anything wrong with the code above? It's not working!

Thanks!

Comment: How do you *know* it's not working?

Comment: "Is there anything wrong with the code above? It's not working!" Seems to answer itself. What isn't working? Do you have an error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988230/can-i-do-sendkeys-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events/596580

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375389

Comment: Well, long story short I have a swiffy object on the page and I can "control" it using different keypresses and one of them is by pressing "P"... I know it's not working because the animation of the swiffy object that should start, isn't...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to tap into the direct controls of your object (call the function that is used for the "P" key press event) rather than trying to get a scripting language to mock a key press?